# Extract rows between two specific cells pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, extract, rows

I need to extract n rows between the cells `epic` and `story` from the column `col2`.

This is my input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['aze ', 'az a', 'az a', 'azs abv','aze ', 'az a', 'azs abv', 'abc 45','wqas', 'foo bar abc', 'foo abv', 'abc 45', 'abc 45'], 'col2': ['epic', 'ac4', 'ac5', 'story','story', 'ac10', 'ac6', 'epic','ac11', 'ac1', 'ac2', 'ac3', 'story'], 'col3': ['hey', 'hello', 'hola', 'yoopy','hawdi', 'yiiha', 'yow', 'yalla', 'yiiha', 'yow', 'yalla', 'yalla', 'yalla']})  
print(df) 

           col1   col2   col3
0          aze    epic    hey
1          az a    ac4  hello
2          az a    ac5   hola
3       azs abv  story  yoopy
4          aze   story  hawdi
5          az a   ac10  yiiha
6       azs abv    ac6    yow
7        abc 45   epic  yalla
8          wqas   ac11  yiiha
9   foo bar abc    ac1    yow
10      foo abv    ac2  yalla
11       abc 45    ac3  yalla
12       abc 45  story  yalla
```

and this is the desired output :

```
          col1    col2    col3
0         az a     ac4    hello
1         az a     ac5    hola
2         wqas     ac11   yiiha
3   foo bar abc    ac1    yow
4       foo abv    ac2    yalla
5        abc 45    ac3    yalla
```

the solution proposed by @ansev gave me this output instead:

```
       col1   col2   col3
0     az a    ac4  hello
1     az a    ac5   hola
2     aze   story  hawdi
3     az a   ac10  yiiha
4  azs abv    ac6    yow
5   abc 45  story  yalla
```

Comment: You have multiple entries named `epic` and `story`. How should this be handled?

Comment: Yes, multiple entries. but I need only to extract the rows between epic and story respectfully.
I don't know if it's doable or not

Comment: I guess every time you have an "epic" entry you will have a "story" one, right?

Comment: yeah, that's correct

Comment: Is possible convert `col2` to list? Like `print (df['col2'].tolist())`

Comment: do you mean col2 in the simple example or in my excel file, col2= Issue Type. but either way, it's possible.

Comment: because problem is cannot test picture data, so ansev cannot test what is wrong

Comment: I'll add it to my post

Comment: copy again the code, there aren't errors

Comment: using `epic = df['Issue Type'].eq('Epic')` and `story = df['Issue Type'].eq('Story')` of course..if it could have lowercase 
and you don't want to distinguish you can use: `epic = df['Issue Type'].str.lower().eq('epic')` and  `story = df['Issue Type'].str.lower().eq('story')`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,[`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.mod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html) 
to detect the change from **epic to story** after setting all values ​​to `False` before the first `epic`.

```
epic = df['col2'].eq('epic') 
story = df['col2'].eq('story')
df.loc[(epic | story).where(epic.cumsum().ge(1), False)
                     .cumsum()
                     .mod(2)
                     .eq(1)
                     .where(~epic, False)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
      col1 col2   col3
0     az a   ac  hello
1  azs abv   ac   hola
```