# Extract rows between two specific cells from a large excel file pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, extract, rows

I need to extract n rows between the cells epic and story from the column `Issue Type`.
when I worked on a simple example, [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274014/extract-rows-between-two-specific-cells-pandas/61274314#61274314) worked perfectly:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['aze ', 'az a', 'az a', 'azs abv','aze ', 'az a', 'azs abv', 'abc 45','wqas', 'foo bar abc', 'foo abv', 'abc 45', 'abc 45'], 'col2': ['epic', 'ac4', 'ac5', 'story','epic', 'story', 'ac6', 'ac7','epic', 'ac1', 'ac2', 'ac3', 'story'], 'col3': ['hey', 'hello', 'hola', 'yoopy','hawdi', 'yiiha', 'yow', 'yalla', 'yiiha', 'yow', 'yalla', 'yalla', 'yalla']}) 
print(df)
Epic = df['col2'].eq('Epic') 
Story = df['col2'].eq('Story')
df1=df.loc[(Epic | Story).where(Epic.cumsum().ge(1), False)
                     .cumsum()
                     .mod(2)
                     .eq(1)
                     .where(~Epic, False)].reset_index(drop=True)
print('\n',df1)
df1.to_excel('EpicStory.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=True)
```

but when I worked on my excel file, as an input, the output was incorrect
This is my input:

[image]

this is the output:
[image]

this is the desired output:

[image]

But I can't wrap my head around it!

Comment: So if this problem is best contact author of code, because there should be some bug of code or some data related problem.

Comment: yeah, I thought so, but I don't know how to contact him! should I just mention him in this question?

Comment: 2 thing - first remove tick of accepting and then add data in text format to question. then add comment under his answer with explain  problem.